# Is this question suitable for CS theory

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions

I posted this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14328/difficulty-in-understanding-the-quantum-algorithm-for-the-abelian-hidden-subgrou) on cs.stackexchange but didn't get any answers. I was wondering if this is suitable for this site?

Comment: I am not an expert but seems ok to me.

Comment: #$%& various comments got zapped by the mgt. anyway, wondering where you got the problem statement, are you working from a textbook or paper? better to cite it

Comment: @vzn It's not from any specific book or paper. I'm just trying to learn the algorithm for AHSP. All the papers and books I've seen don't exactly explain the last step properly.

Comment: fyi [nielsen & chuang](http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Computation-Information-Anniversary-Edition/dp/1107002176) seems to be one of the best refs on QM computing. covers it p240. also some info on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_subgroup_problem)

Comment: it says it does a [QFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Fourier_transform) on the left register & then samples it.